# Observable from RefCount() doesn't stop publishing

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, rx.net

I am building a message processing pipeline and noticed that when the very last observer disposes subscription the observable is still pumping data through.

I have looked at the Rx docs and my assumption based on it was that `RefCount()` would disconnect the observable once the very last observer has unsubscribed, as per the docs:

*RefCount then keeps track of how many other observers subscribe to it and does not disconnect from the underlying connectable Observable **until the last observer has done so**.*

To illustrate the issue I have created a very minimalistic example below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _ = SimulateObservableIssue();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task SimulateObservableIssue()
    {
        IObservable<int> source = Observable.Create<int>(async (observer) =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Source publishing {i}");
                observer.OnNext(i);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            observer.OnCompleted();

            return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observable is disposed"));
        });

        var multiSource = source.Publish().RefCount();

        var subscription = multiSource.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Observer received: " + x));

        await Task.Delay(3000);

        subscription.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("Subscription disposed");

    }
}
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPA3U.png)

```xml
Source publishing 0
Observer received: 0
Source publishing 1
Observer received: 1
Source publishing 2
Observer received: 2
Subscription disposed
Source publishing 3
Source publishing 4
Source publishing 5
Source publishing 6
Source publishing 7
Source publishing 8
Source publishing 9
Observable is disposed
```

Why after `subscription.Dispose()` the observable is still trying to produce data?

Answer (score 1):

Your `source` observable doesn't respect the Observable contract you mention. If you replace `source` with this:

```
    var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Do(i => Console.WriteLine($"Source publishing {i}"), () => Console.WriteLine("Observable is disposed"))
        .Take(10);
```

...you'll see that it works as intended.

As for why, think of an observable having two phases: Subscribe and Observe. Code that happens during Subscribe-time always happens, regardless of subscription cancellation. `Observable.Create` code is all subscribe code.

The observable I wrote is all observe code (as most observable code should be). So it responds appropriately to subscription cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would be the correct way of creating custom observable then?

Comment: "Custom observable" can mean a lot of things. Most likely you don't want or need one, and would rather build one out of the standard operators as I did above. What do you want your observable to do?

Comment: As per my example, I would like my observable to multi-cast some data to multiple subscribers. I have achieved this already in the actual implementation but as highlighted the question facing a bit of inefficiency when the very last observer unsubscribes and the data is still being produced. So my question really is what would be an alternative to the 'Observable.Create' for custom observable implementation that would respect Observable contract and RefCount would be able to handle subscribers internally correctly? I could handle the state but RefCount seemed as nice out of the box solution.

Comment: Yes: `RefCount` is fine. What are you doing in `Observable.Create` that can't be represented in other Observable operators?

Comment: Well, my example in the question is probably too minimalistic to illustrate what I am doing in actual implementation. However, let's say I would like an observable to produce objects with different numeric values, I might need to explore more Observable operators but I can't see a straightforward way to do that at the moment at least from those in the example provided above. Do you know if there are any that I am missing but could use as an alternative to 'Observable.Create<ObjectX>'?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are observing is not related to the `RefCount` operator. If you subscribe directly to the `source` instead of the `multiSource`, the behavior will be the same.

The problem is related to how you are using the `Observable.Create` with an asynchronous lambda in order to create the custom observable. The Rx library has no way of terminating the `Task` that is created by the asynchronous lambda. So although the observer has unsubscribed, the task keeps going. Tasks in general can only be terminated cooperatively, and the [standard mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) for terminating a no longer needed task is by signaling a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) that is observed by the task. The Rx library supports this pattern by the `Observable.Create` overload with the signature below:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Create<TResult>(
    Func<IObserver<TResult>, CancellationToken, Task> subscribeAsync);
```

The supplied `CancellationToken` is provided and managed by the library, and your responsibility is to honor a cancellation signal by terminating the loop. One way to do it is by calling the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method in various points inside the loop. In the specific example it is sufficient to pass the `CancellationToken` as an argument to the `Task.Delay` method:

```
var source = Observable.Create<int>(async (observer, cancellationToken) =>
{
    cancellationToken.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Token is canceled"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Source publishing {i}");
        observer.OnNext(i);
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
    }
    observer.OnCompleted();
    Console.WriteLine($"Source is completed");
});
```

In case of cancellation the exception thrown by the `await Task.Delay` is not going to be observed by anyone, because at this point the observable will have no observers. There is no reason to try/catch it, unless you want to log it.

You may have noticed that the lambda does not return a `Disposable`. This happens because the role of the `Disposable` is now played by the supplied `CancellationToken`. Under the hood the library is using a [`CancellationDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh212123(v=vs.103)), that when disposed is cancelling an internal `CancellationTokenSource`, the `Token` of which is passed to your method.

Comment: Upvoted: Using the `CancellationToken` is the correct solution for this scenario.